# Why is ethanol more acidic than acetone?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, reaction-mechanism, stability, inductive-effect

The acidity of a compound is determined by the stability of its conjugate base and the major structure of enolate has a negative charge on the Oxygen atom. Moreover, the negative charge on the O-atom of ethoxide is increased by the [+I effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_effect) of $\ce{-CH2CH3}$.

[image]

Image source: [chem.libretext.org](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Map%3A_Organic_Chemistry_(Vollhardt_and_Schore)/18%3A_Enols_Enolates_and_the_Aldol_Condensation%3A_ab-Unsaturated_Aldehydes_and_Ketones/18.01%3A_Acidity__of_Aldehydes_and__Ketones%3A_Enolate__Ions#:%7E:text=Of%20the%20two%20resonance%20structures,greater%20electronegativity%20of%20the%20oxygen)

So, how is ethoxide more stable than enolate?

Comment: If enol was the major tautomer, then it could be stronger, but it isn't.

Comment: @Neha if you got your answer, please feel free to self-answer it. Self-answering is always appreciated and it will help future readers.

Comment: @NilayGhosh Well... I think only *good* self answers are really appreciated. Usually, if more experienced user then one that asks, answers, then result is better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking the data from [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/41697/which-factors-determine-the-ketoenol-ratio-for-aldehydes-ketones-and-1-3-dica) by ron, the equilibrium constant for the keto-enol tautomerism seen in acetone is

$$K_\mathrm{eq} = \frac{\text{[enol]}}{\text{[carbonyl]}}$$

$$
\begin{array}{lc}
\hline
\text{compound} & K_\mathrm{eq} \\
\hline
\text{acetaldehyde} & 6 \times 10^{-7} \\
\text{acetone} & 5 \times 10^{-9} \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

This means that acetone exists predominantly (if not wholly) in its keto form. For every one molecule of the enol form observed, we can expect $\pu{2E8}$ molecules of the keto form.

Because of this, any deprotonation that takes place in acetone will have to be via breaking a $\ce{C-H}$ bond, and that is not a simple thing to do when you compare it to deprotonating an $\ce{O-H}$ bond in ethanol. Thus ethanol is more acidic than acetone.