# Why enol is unstable?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Alkynes undergo acid-catalyzed addition of water across the triple bond in the presence of mercuric ion catalyst. The products are enol and keto. I want to know why is keto more stable than enol.

Comment: Try a Google search... "keto-enol tautomerism"

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18904/which-is-the-more-stable-enol-form

Answer (score -2):

It's is basically because in keto form the C=O bond is more stable than the C=C bond in enol. And the difference is probably close to 12 kcal.