# Enol percentage comparison between 1,3 diketones and 1,2 cyclopentadione

Tags: organic-chemistry

To what extent does 1,2-cyclopentadione exist in enol form? Will it be more than for 1,3 diketones? 1,3-Diketone with active methylene groups can form hydrogen bonds with a 6-membered ring structure. 1,2-cyclopentadione could also form hydrogen bonds, but it forms only a 5-membered ring.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Chemistry.SE. I edited your question to hopefully improve the clarity of what you are asking.

Comment: Also, this answer explains some of the factors that contribute to increased enol percentage, although it does not answer your question:https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18904/which-is-the-more-stable-enol-form/18917#18917