# Which of the following compounds possess more than one percent enol content?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability, hydrogen-bond, enolate-chemistry

> Which of the following compounds possess more than one percent enol content?
>
> [image]

I understood that stability of enols are dependent on the hydrogen bonding in the compounds. But here, what is the significance of *more than one percent enol content*?

Comment: I would like to express my disagreement with the assertion that the stability of enols would mainly be dependent on inter- and intra- molecular hydrogen bonding.

Comment: @user79161 I mean that h-bonding is one of the factor that could be used for determining the stability of Enols. It need not be the primary factor.

Comment: Especially because of the nice representations of the formulae (for easier reading, consider to rotate labels, though [entry **i**]), a more useful question were the comparison of the entries by line to justify which ones are more likely to enolize, than others -- for example in the line of **a** to **d**.  For some, $\log{}K$ may depend on the molecule's structure as well as (if there is) the solvent molecules.  Or -- guessing -- are you literally looking for a _tautomer database_ [example](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jcim.9b01156)?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18904/which-is-the-more-stable-enol-form
This might help you;@Ron's answer was very extensive.
Note that, as Buttonwood pointed out, a fruitful exercise would be to compare likelihood of enolization. To compare the respective percentages would need you to carry out an experiment and interpret that data.

Answer (score 1):

All the compounds that have a relation $\alpha-\beta$ between the carbonyl groups. The hydrogen between two $\ce{CO}$ is very acid because two electrowithdrawing remove electron density from the $\ce{C-O}$ bond. Therefore for this kind of compound the most stable for is the enol. In Organic Chemistry this is very useful in creating new carbon-carbon bonds in mild conditions like in aldoholic reactions, Michael reactions and so on. See the very good book of Marc Loudon, Organic Chemistry.